# How to redirect multiple ECS log streams into a single log stream in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I currently have my application running in ECS. I have enabled the awslogs agent indicating the Log group and the region. Everything works great, send the logs to the Log group and create a Log stream. However, every time I restart the container, it creates a new Log stream.

Is there a way that instead of creating a Log stream as the container restarts, it all goes into a single Log stream?
I've been looking for a solution for a long time and I haven't found anything.

For example, instead of there being 2 Log streams, there is only 1 each time the container is restarted.

[image]

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: No, each container will have a separate log stream. Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It can be done by doing custom logging any of many ways, but if you want to use the simple awslogs, then no. But really why would you want to? This makes it clear which task logged what.

Comment: @MarkB Answering your question, not really. I simply wanted to move all the Log streams into one. It's that every time I create a new version of my Task Definition, it creates a new Log stream and as they accumulate, I just wanted to tell you where to put the logs in a single Log stream.

Comment: It can't be done and is honestly a bad idea because then you won't be able to separate out the logs from your individual deployments. It would be especially problematic if you scaled up to more than one concurrent container.

Comment: @theherk As I replied to Mark B , I was just looking for a way to do it. Of course if you know how to do it, I would be grateful if you support me by giving me the information about it.

Comment: @Gamaor Forgive me then, I understood you to be tied to the awslogs driver, in which case you can't do what you want. I'll add a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the [PutLogEvents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html) api directly. Beyond that you can get as fancy as you want. You could use a firelens side car container in your task to handle all events using a logging api that writes directly to cloudwatch.

For example, you can do this in python with [boto3 cloudwatch put_log_events](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.put_log_events)

```py
response = boto3.client("logs").put_log_events(
    logGroupName="your-log-group",
    logStreamName="your-log-stream",
    logEvents=[
        {"timestamp": 123, "message": "log message"},
    ],
)
```